# Django + Haystack + Solr Error while generating xml

Tags: python, xml, django, solr, django-haystack

I am trying to run "python manage.py `build_solr_schema` while encountered with error that is not letting me generate the xml from database. My solr server is up and running fine and I can see the solr server initial page. Following is the complete error code.

Error:

```
Save the following output to 'schema.xml' and place it in your Solr configuratio
n directory.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->

<schema name="default" version="1.5">
  <types>
    <fieldtype name="string"  class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitN
orms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" omit
Norms="true"/>
    <fieldtype name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>

    <!-- Numeric field types that manipulate the value into
         a string value that isn't human-readable in its internal form,
         but with a lexicographic ordering the same as the numeric ordering,
         so that range queries work correctly. -->
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms=
"true" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" omitNo
rms="true" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" omitNorm
s="true" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" omit
Norms="true" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="sint" class="solr.SortableIntField" sortMissingLast="true"
omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="slong" class="solr.SortableLongField" sortMissingLast="true
" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sfloat" class="solr.SortableFloatField" sortMissingLast="tr
ue" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sdouble" class="solr.SortableDoubleField" sortMissingLast="
true" omitNorms="true"/>

    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms
="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" omitN
orms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" omitNor
ms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" omi
tNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precision
Step="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <!-- A Trie based date field for faster date range queries and date faceting
. -->
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisio
nStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <fieldType name="point" class="solr.PointType" dimension="2" subFieldSuffix=
"_d"/>
    <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordina
te"/>
    <fieldtype name="geohash" class="solr.GeoHashField"/>

    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="
100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopword
s.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt"
ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopword
s.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignore
Case="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">

      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt
"/>
        <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead
 of PorterStemFilterFactory:
          <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignore
Case="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt
"/>
        <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead
 of PorterStemFilterFactory:
          <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">

      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="ngram" class="solr.TextField" >
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15"
 />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="1"
>
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" ge
nerateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" spli
tOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize=
"15" side="front" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" ge
nerateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" spli
tOnCaseChange="1"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
  </types>

  <fields>
    <!-- general -->
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="fal
se" required="true"/>
    <field name="django_ct" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValu
ed="false"/>
    <field name="django_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValu
ed="false"/>
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored ="true"/>

    <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_l"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text_en"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_f"  type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_d"  type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_dt" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_p" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="fa
lse"/>


    <field name="text" type="ngram" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="fa
lse" />

    <field name="content_auto" type="edge_ngram" indexed="true" stored="true" mu
ltiValued="false" />

  </fields>

  <!-- field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness. -->
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

  <!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->

  <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>

  <!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
  <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
</schema>

Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <bound method Solr._
_del__ of <pysolr.Solr object at 0x0384DD70>> ignored
```

models.py:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    sku = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)
    default = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='default_category', null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_detail', kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
# Create your views here.
from .models import Product
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductListView, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)

        return context

class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
```

Comment: Getting something similar here. Did you find the answer?

Comment: This simplest solution worked for me with whoosh, solr and elasticsearch. Just implement as it is and change settings for solr. You might need to install solr server. http://nanvel.name/2013/07/django-haystack-example